# RStudio: Is there any way to get a data frame to show the column number using the View() function?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

I've searched on google, here and on youtube but I've not seen anyone ask this, thus I doubt it is possible.
But I have a data frame with a decent number of rows (25) and I'm making a correlation plot between the numerical variables and a heat map of Chi-Squared Test p-values between the categorical variables.

To do so I need to refer to the column ID for each relevant variable.
**I'm just wondering if there is a way to make the View() function display column numbers by default, similar to how there is an index column for row numbers.**

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [label the columns](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/labelled/vignettes/intro_labelled.html), as `View` [displays labels](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205175388-Using-the-Data-Viewer):

```
library(labelled)
var_label(iris) <- as.list(setNames(as.character(1:ncol(iris)),colnames(iris)))
View(iris)
```

[image]

Comment: That's really fantastic, thank you so much! Up-voted!

Comment: Done! Thanks again, all the best

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

```r
set.seed(42)

# example dataframe
df_0 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(3),
                   y = rnorm(3),
                   z = rnorm(3))
# copy to leave original copy intact
df_1 <- df_0
# rename columns with indices
colnames(df_1) <- 1:ncol(df_1)
# produces
df_1
#>            1          2           3
#> 1  1.3709584  0.6328626  1.51152200
#> 2 -0.5646982  0.4042683 -0.09465904
#> 3  0.3631284 -0.1061245  2.01842371

View(df_1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: That's pretty clever, thank you for your help, up-voted.